# PHP7 Yii2 MSSQL NonEnglish Quote Error

Tags: php, sql-server, yii2

Here Is First My Question In StackOverFlow

[MyEnvironment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WiZJ.gif)
My Environment
Centos7 Yii2.0.9 PHP7.0.9
MSsql Use PDODBLib And FreeTDS
Connection Is Ok Table Show Is Ok(Where clause Is Nothing)
I Thought Think PHP7 Is Every Ok
But If the Where clause exists does not work

Debug/Logs Tab Show Below:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [pw26] WHERE ([w26_kind]=7) AND ([w26_title] LIKE 0x25ed8c9c25)
```

Before PHP 5.6 Show Below:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [pw26] WHERE ([w26_kind]=7) AND ([w26_title] LIKE '%팜%')
```

Only it occurs in non-English Word

I Find This Yii2/db/Schema.php

```
public function quoteValue($str)
{
    if (!is_string($str)) {
        return $str;
    }

    if (($value = $this->db->getSlavePdo()->quote($str)) !== false) {
        return $value;
    } else {
        // the driver doesn't support quote (e.g. oci)
        return "'" . addcslashes(str_replace("'", "''", $str), "\000\n\r\\\032") . "'";
    }
}
```

Top Code Change Like Below

```
if (($value = $this->db->getSlavePdo()->quote($str)) !== false) {
```

Afer:

```
if (false) {
```

Finaly Debug/Logs Tab Show Below:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [pw26] WHERE ([w26_kind]=7) AND ([w26_title] LIKE '%팜%')
```

But, still The data does not appear.

Comment: After reading your question its hard to determine your problem.. pls be specific what is your issue ?? and what you want to perform ?

Comment: I Want Use php7 But I Dont Because Non-English Quote Error

Answer (score 1):

Freetds manages charset from verison 7.0. Edit /etc/freetds/freetds.conf or add version param to db settings 'dsn'.

Charset attribute doesn't work for MS SQL, you have to add it to 'dsn'.

```
'db' => [
     'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
     'dsn' => 'dblib:version=7.0;host=192.168.1.2;dbname=devdb;charset=UTF-8',
     'username' => 'devuser',
     'password' => 'devpasswd',
     //'charset' => 'UTF-8'
],
```

Comment: current freetds.conf is same above(7.0 -> 8.0) but not work